# How do I change the background of a ListFragment item without removing the android ripple animations?

Tags: java, android, animation

Right now whenever I change the background of any element in my application all those ripple touch animations are gone even for buttons.

Is there a way to change the background color but keep the default animations?

I have tried changing the AppTheme background too but it also removes all riple animatinos.

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Is the only fix to make my own animation for user touches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `foreground` which will act as another layer on top of the background of the view:

`android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"`